# how can I unfold my php code in emacs?

Tags: php, emacs, code-folding

I'm a newbie in emacs 23.2.1. I want to edit my php files, and I got emacs' php mode from https://code.google.com/p/mewde/, but when I open php files and enter php-mode,this mode automatically folded some parts of my scripts,

```
<?php...
?>
```

I've tried every keys (got from the web, emacs-wiki,and C-h ? ,just like C-c C-c , C-c @ C-c .etc)but no one works, can anyone tell me the key to unfold my codes?

this is really a easy but bad but serious problem, I'll thank you and the god very much if you can show me a direction.

note:I'm using Ubuntu 11.04

[solved]:php-mode on https://code.google.com/p/mewde/ depends on c-mode,outline-mode,and hs-mode(hide-show-mode)to manage codes,so I use keys in outline-mode to hide and show the blocks.In my emacs,use "C-c @ C-a" to show all codes, and use "C-c @ C-t" to hide a body.***thanks to Jay's remind !!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
C-c C-o 
C-c C-f
```

Or just going straight to 'menu Commands->Unfold All Output'

Comment: Great!!I've got it!!thank you and god very much!!when type in "C-c C-o",message shows:"Syntactic symbol to change: topmost-intro" and when type in "C-c C-f", it opens www.php.net in my browser.But after I search the menu ,I find it is in "outline"->"showall",and it work!!

Comment: So did any of my suggestions work? Are you doing this on a remote server or in a Desktop environment for Ubuntu 11.04? Because your config for key bindings could be different.

Comment: I've turned off menu-bar in my .emacs file with (menu-bar-mode -1) before I hit this problem. _menu-bar sometimes is helpful_ ,**Thank you !**

Comment: Yes it is. There are actually a lot of commands that their aren't hotkeys for in emacs. You can of course rebind the hotkeys to all the different functions available, but then again there are only so many hotkeys combos

Comment: But no need to have that menu bar eat precious screen space, encouraging you to leave your hands away from the keyboard :o ! Use `M-x menu-bar-open` (may be bound to `F10`).